# Limpar botão radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, css, c, banco-de-dados

Bom dia 
Gostaria de saber como faço para limpar o que foi clicado no botão radiobutton, porque nos textBox eu uso o nome.Clear();
Gostaria de saber como faço no radio button

Obrigado.

Comment: Esses botões estão dentro de uma form? há mais elementos que queres limpar ou só esses botões? Nesse caso basta `elemento.checked = false;`

Comment: Sim, tem mais elementos que estão sendo limpos

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer `form.reset()` no elemento `<form>`?

Comment: Deu certo Obrigado !!!

Answer (score 1):

Basta mudar o atributo do elemento de `checked` para `false`.

Em jQuery, você pode selecionar pelo `id` ou pelo `name`, por exemplo:

```
$('input[name=Choose]').attr('checked',false);
```

Em Javascript puro:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName("Choose");
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
      ele[i].checked = false;
```

Retirado do [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554116/how-to-clear-radio-button-in-javascript) em inglês em resposta dada pelo [NVRAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57582/nvram)

Comment: Deu certo !!! Obr

Comment: Por nada. Pode marcar as resposta como aceita, por favor? Aí fica documentado aqui na comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Para desmarcar um input especifico basta fazeres `elemento.checked = false;`.

No caso de teres vários, tens de os iterar e fazer um a um. Algo como:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++){
    inputs[i].checked = false;
}
```

Mas muitas vezes o que se pretende é re-iniciar um formulário, isso pode ser feito com:

```
document.querySelector('form').reset();
```